# Non-subscription gui software to manually rotate a page in a pdf by a few degrees for deskewing

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf

I'm looking for a piece of software that can run on macos, that has a gui, and that enables the user to manually rotate a page in a pdf by a few degrees (say up to 5) in order to deskew the image.  I would like to be able to tweak the amount of rotation, although if the software had a suggestion that would be fine.  (I should clarify that this should be something that runs locally on my own machine, and not something online.)

My particular application is for scanned images of text, and i do intend to subsequently OCR them; however the rotation/deskewing software need not be aware of this.  Also, it has been pointed out that typically you rotate an image stack before you put it in a pdf, not afterwards.  This is absolutely true, but i did not make the pdfs that i am trying to fix.

Free or open source software would be great, but i could also use closed source, just as long as the software was not licensed on a subscription basis.  That is, whatever the cost is, i would like to pay it up front, once and forever.

And, the software wouldn't have to run on every pdf, just scanned images.  So it could be something simple-minded, just as long as i can rotate each page by an arbitrary, but small amount, and eye-ball it to make sure the result is not skewed.

Comment: Are these scanned images text? And which you want to OCR? Or some other purpose? Is it critical that the image is rotated inside the PDF? More usual would be to rotate the image (JPEG, TIFF, etc.) before creating the PDF - for that you would have a wide choice of software.

Comment: Thanks @Gilby for your very perceptive points.  I've added them to the text of the question.   (Yes, it is for OCR, but the sw should not need to know this.  Yes, it is better to deskew before making a pdf, but i did not make the pdfs, i just want to repair them.  And yes, i would like to fix the pdfs without taking them apart and recreating them, so i guess you could call it 'critical').

Comment: I have constructed a long-winded answer. The simple answer is Nitro PDF Pro - expensive but not subscription.

Comment: Thanks @Gilby , i think your answer (to use nitro-pdf) solves the problem as stated, so i accepted it.   (I also would not have known that you answered except that the site sent me mail about it today 2024-02-28.  Not sure what triggers this.)  And thanks for being very detailed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible workflows:

1. Use OCR product which will de-skew;
2. Unpack the PDF, rotate the image (TIFF, JPEG, etc), recreate the PDF, and OCR.

Which workflow and which products (cheap or not) will depend on your purpose. You may want a PDF where the OCR layer is a good quality and precisely aligned to the image. Or your needs may be simpler, for example, to create a PDF that is searchable within a PDF reader and whose content is indexed by Spotlight.

In more detail, using a test image rotated 5 degrees and converted to PDF:

**OCR with de-skew.**
A good OCR product will open the PDF (with the 5-degree image), de-skew it, and OCR.  For my test, I used [Nitro PDF Pro](https://www.gonitro.com/pdf-pro/macos) (not cheap!). The output was a PDF with the embedded image automatically straightened and a good quality OCR layer.  I don't think you will get this functionality and quality with a low cost or open source product.

But if your purpose is to create a searchable PDF, then I have found [OwlOCR](https://owlocr.com) to be a budget product that is easy to use. With OwlOCR the OCR layer for the 5-degree image did not look very good, but the words were correctly detected. Good word detection is all that is needed for searchability.

OwlOCR uses the Apple OCR engine, often referred to as LiveText. As a bonus, it includes Finder Quick Actions which you can use on individual files.

**Unpack the PDF, rotate, recreate, and OCR**

Use [FileJuicer](https://echoone.com/filejuicer/) to unpack the PDF, and rotate the resultant image with your favorite image editor (I use low-cost [Acorn](https://flyingmeat.com/acorn/) for simple things like this). Recreate a PDF from the image - Finder has a Quick Action to create a PDF from an image. OCR the PDF with its straightened image using any decent OCR product (I would use OwlOCR).  The PDF produced by OwlOCR now has a good looking OCR layer.

My views on the products I have mentioned:

- Nitro PDF Pro is an expensive but very comprehensive PDF editor. It was cheaper when I bought it as PDFPen. I don't know of a low-cost PDF editor with good OCR.
- OwlOCR is low-cost OCR (not a PDF editor) - I use it frequently.
- FileJuicer is, in my view, over-priced. I bought it long ago when it was much cheaper. If you don't have an ongoing use for it, there is a trial.
- Acorn is excellent as a low cost image editor. Again there is a trial. You could likely use free and open-source [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org) as an alternative.

I am a paid user of those products and have no other connection to their developers.

I have not mentioned open-source Tesseract because I have found it rather poor at accurate OCR.

**Important note**

If your need is just to search in a PDF reader, you don't *need* to OCR the PDF.  Preview OCRs in the background and the PDF is searchable within Preview.  This works with my 5-degree image.

Answer (score 0):

[GraphicConverter](https://www.lemkesoft.de/en/products/graphicconverter/) can open PDF and edit/save individual pages.  It saves as image, but that is not a problem if you intend to use OCR on them.

It can rotate, and "unskew."  For unskew, you mark the corners of what should be a rectangle, and it gets converted to that,

I take photos of headstones from an angle (due to sun position and shadows) and use unskew to make them look head-on.  I use rotate to straighten scanned pages of my grandfather’s diary so I can then OCR it with [tesseract](https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/Home.html).

Answer (score 0):

## OCRmyPDF + unpaper

While not a graphical solution, `ocrmypdf` and its [support for `unpaper`](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#control-of-unpaper) are worth investigating.

Both tools are open source and available through the [`brew`](https://brew.sh) project:

> ### [OCRmyPDF](https://ocrmypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html)
>
> OCRmyPDF adds an optical character recognition (OCR) text layer to scanned PDF files, allowing them to be searched.
>
> PDF is the best format for storing and exchanging scanned documents. Unfortunately, PDFs can be difficult to modify. OCRmyPDF makes it easy to apply image processing and OCR (recognized, searchable text) to existing PDFs.

```
brew install ocrmypdf
```

> ### [unpaper](https://github.com/unpaper/unpaper)
>
> unpaper is a post-processing tool for scanned sheets of paper, especially for book pages that have been scanned from previously created photocopies. The main purpose is to make scanned book pages better readable on screen after conversion to PDF. Additionally, unpaper might be useful to enhance the quality of scanned pages before performing optical character recognition (OCR).
>
> unpaper tries to clean scanned images by removing dark edges that appeared through scanning or copying on areas outside the actual page content (e.g. dark areas between the left-hand-side and the right-hand-side of a double- sided book-page scan).
>
> The program also tries to detect misaligned centering and rotation of pages and will automatically straighten each page by rotating it to the correct angle. This process is called "deskewing".